# Is "Well-spokenness" a phrase in current use ?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

I had never heard or read this before, but a job ad required "well-spokenness".  The American Heritage Dictionary never even mentions "spokenness".  Nor does the OED online. Although I think I understand what it means, does it exist ?  If it does, what is considered well-spokenness in the US and in England ?

Comment: He did respond to what you asked. He is saying that it's existence is not dependent on a dictionary specifically referencing it. He also responded to the question of what would be considered well-spokenness.

Comment: The adjective *well-spoken* carries some [racial baggage](http://theracecardproject.com/youre-well-spoken-isnt-a-compliment/) here in the States.

Comment: @BrianDonovan Do you really mean racial ?  Or social-class ?   Does it mean speaking English with no foreign accent ?  No domestic ethnic accent ?

Comment: @DaveMagner He deleted his first comment. And then I deleted mine too.

Comment: @Luis I do mean racial. See my link above. The term is used in ways that betray an assumption that any coincidence of articulacy with black skin is unexpected, noteworthy, an aberration, marking the black person with whom white elites can feel relatively comfortable.

Comment: @BrianDonovan  I've read it and the passage is clear.  It's a subtlety I would never make out by myself.  Although half of our population is genetically black, we have that kind of stuff down here too.  It's a racist way of avoiding the accusation of being a racist. (Racism and racist actions are crimes here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What *well-spokenness* means is trivially explained by taking away the *-ness* suffix and looking up what you’re left with.  Your job ad therefore asks simply that the applicant be ***well-spoken***.

The OED gives as sense 1 of *well-spoken* the following:

> 1. Of a person: Gifted with good or ready speech; courteous and refined in speech.

It also cites *well-spoken-of-ness* as a nonce word.

There really is no need for a dictionary to include all possible terms producible by elementary [derivational morphology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_%28linguistics%29), such as adding *-ness* to *well-spoken* to produce a new headword *well-spokenness* — and every reason for them not to do so.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I couldn't find the word "spokenness" in two first-rate dictionaries. (http://public.oed.com/?post_type=page&s=spokenness)  As I had never heard nor read the word before, I wondered whether it was a phrase somebody had coined. I'm aware that not all adjectives take the suffix –ness to form their abstract nouns. My doubt, therefore, was more about the existence of the word "spokenness" than the meaning of "well-spokenness" or "well-spoken", and my question was whether

Comment: and my question was whether the word exists, is currently used, and what is considered "well-spokenness" in the US and in the UK.   I can see there are special connotations, as someone has already mentioned above that the phrase has some racial baggage in the US.   Maybe the fact that I'm not a native speaker prevents me from making myself one hundred percent understood. Feel free to edit the question as you feel appropriate.

Comment: PS: You may say that dictionaries are not supposed to show all words formed by adding -ness to an adjective.  Well, mine does (The American Heritage).  I often find the abstract noun or adverb  after the definition. (e.g. under "serious" you find the definition and then, "seriously"adv. seriousness,n. Since I didn't see "spokenness" right at the end of "well-spoken", I thought it didn't exist.  Sorry if I have to be this long to explain what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

No I have not heard of such a usage maybe the drafter of the job advert is a non native English speaker and is showing off trying to make the advert sound more important than it really is.

Answer (score 0):

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=well-spokenness&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,well%20-%20spokenness;,c0) shows it is used  in American English but not  very common.

The adjective [well-spoken](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=well-spokenness,%20well-spoken&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,well%20-%20spokenness;,c0;.t1;,well%20-%20spoken;,c0) is more used.

Comment: From Ngram I gather the phrase appears 4 times out of 10.000.000.000 words, in the year 2000, which means 1 out of 2.500.000.000.  I wonder how many pages a book containing 2.500.000.000 words must have.

Answer (score 0):

**"-ness"** can sometimes be tacked on the ends of words to make nouns of adjectives; normally you create adjectives from nouns; it will in most cases look like someone trying to think of a synonym, and failing.

As for myself, the first synonym I thought of was, [*eloquence*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eloquence). (I think the synonyms *articulacy* and *articulateness* on this page substantiate my claim.)

As for the use in a job ad, it may be a (cultural) *[code word](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/code%20word)*; I would heed the comments saying so.

I find it hilariously ironic that anger and prejudice should yield such an immediate result. :) They want someone "possessing eloquence", while lacking same. On the other hand, maybe it's a need to be satiated and the entire reason to hire, but from human nature I strongly doubt it. :)